# Consulta KivyClock

Tags: python, kivy

Mi consulta es muy simple. Si yo tengo 4 clock.schedule_interval(), los 4 funcionan o solo uno? Estan declarados asi:

```
KivyClock.schedule_interval(inicial.update, 1)
KivyClock.schedule_interval(inicial.prenderTiraParaAlarma, 30)
KivyClock.schedule_interval(inicial.prenderLuzConAplauso, 1)
KivyClock.schedule_interval(inicial.verificarAlarma, 1)
```

Los 3 que tienen como argumento 1, cada 1 seg hacen su funcion y el que tiene el 30, hace su funcion cada 30 seg no?

Comment: Así debería ser, sí. ¿Lo has probado? ¿Es que no funciona como esperabas?

Comment: Si lo probé, específicamente la función verificar alarma lo que hace es fijarse si es la hora y minuto para que suene la alarma pero por alguna razón no hace nada ni siquiera un print pero la función update si funciona

Comment: A lo mejor hacía falta ver el resto del código. Entiendo que la función `verificarAlarma()` tiene dentro código (un print por ejemplo) y que no ves que se esté ejecutando. Y habrá que ver qué hace `update()`, no vaya a ser que acapare el hilo o haga algo que impida que se ejecuten las otras funciones programadas para ese mismo instante.